# Disabling a discord bot for a set time using a command in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been trying to figure this out for a little while, but given that I'm mostly just slapping other people's code together and trying to troubleshoot what goes wrong, I lack a lot of the knowledge needed to do this.

I'm trying to make a bot that, when someone in the server uses the word "the" in any context (even without the bot's prefix), it corrects them with "da" (this is a running joke, please don't roast me for it lmfao). With what it does, it can be annoying - so I'd like to have people be able to disable it for something like 5 minutes at a time, and have it not send messages. The problem is, I have so little experience with python that I'm basically just guessing here. How would I go about making a command that, when triggered, would keep the bot from sending messages for a set amount of time?

Right now, the way that it's sending messages is by checking if the message contains "the", so would it be possible to have it also check something like if a boolean is true before sending?

Here's the main block of code that's responsible for the sending. I am aware that it's probably suboptimal, and if you're so inclined, feel free to explain to me how I could make it better!

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if ('the') in message.content:
        await message.channel.send('i think you meant da :rolling_eyes:')
```

Thanks!

(Also, is there any way that I would be able to only have it respond if "the" is by itself, and not in a word? I tried just making it have spaces before and after, but that didn't work if a message started or ended with it. I figured this probably didn't warrant its own post, since I'm probably just stupid lmao)

Comment: do you use `commands.Bot` or `discord.Client`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a global variable to store a value and edit it from different places

```py
correct_the = True

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global correct_the
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    words = message.content.lower().split(" ") # make a list of all words
    # like this -> ["the", "dogs", "and", "cats"]
    if 'the' in words:
        if correct_the: # check if it should correct it
            await message.channel.send('i think you meant da :rolling_eyes:')

    if message.content.startswith("!disable"): # or make this as command if you use commands.Bot
        if not correct_the:
            print("already disabled")
        else:
            correct_the = False
            await asyncio.sleep(5*60) # sleeps 5min
            correct_the = True
```